# why not close dropdown when click outside in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown in my design that should be deleted when clicked anywhere other than `.categories.menu`.
That is, to lose its show class and close the `.categories.menu`.
At the end of the code I wrote, if this section (`categoriesMenu.classList.remove ("show")`) is run, it will prevent the dropdown of the show class altogether.
so I want to close the menu whenever a user clicks outside the menu.

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
  if (elem.className.indexOf(className) !== -1) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(className, '');
  } else {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') + ' ' + className;
  }

  return elem;
}

function toggleDisplay(elem) {
  const curDisplayStyle = elem.style.display;

  if (curDisplayStyle === 'none' || curDisplayStyle === '') {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function toggleMenuDisplay(e) {
  const dropdown = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const menu = dropdown.querySelector('.menu');
  toggleClass(menu, 'show');
}

function handleOptionSelected(e) {
  toggleClass(e.target.parentNode, 'show');
  const id = e.target.id;
  const newValue = e.target.textContent + ' ';
  const titleElem = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown--title');
  titleElem.textContent = newValue;
}


const dropdownTitle = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown--title');
const dropdownOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .menu.categories a');
dropdownTitle.addEventListener('click', toggleMenuDisplay);
dropdownOptions.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', handleOptionSelected));

var categoriesMenu = document.querySelector('.categories.menu');
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
var categoriesMenuShow = categoriesMenu.classList.contains("show");
var isClickInsideElement = categoriesMenu.contains(event.target);
  if (isClickInsideElement == categoriesMenuShow ) {
      // categoriesMenu.classList.remove("show")
    }
  });
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown::before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
  color: var(--cbl);
}

.dropdown .dropdown--title {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  top: 45px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--cwh);
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
}

.dropdown .menu.show {
  max-height: 20em !important;
}

.dropdown .menu.show a {
  color: var(--cbl);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
}

.dropdown .menu a {
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  color: var(--cbl);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--cblo40);
}

.dropdown .menu a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown--title">Choose category</div>
  <div class="categories menu">
    <a href="#" data-category="[15,16,26,27]" class="clicked">All</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/other/" data-category="15">Other</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/electronics/" data-category="16">Electronics</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/sports/" data-category="26">Sports</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/toys/" data-category="27">Toys &amp; Games</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So just to be clear then, you want to close the menu whenever a user clicks outside the menu?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```js
function toggleClass(elem, className) {
  if (elem.className.indexOf(className) !== -1) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(className, '');
  } else {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace(/\s+/g, ' ') + ' ' + className;
  }

  return elem;
}

function toggleDisplay(elem) {
  const curDisplayStyle = elem.style.display;

  if (curDisplayStyle === 'none' || curDisplayStyle === '') {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function toggleMenuDisplay(e) {
  const dropdown = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const menu = dropdown.querySelector('.menu');
  toggleClass(menu, 'show');
}

function handleOptionSelected(e) {
  toggleClass(e.target.parentNode, 'show');
  const id = e.target.id;
  const newValue = e.target.textContent + ' ';
  const titleElem = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown--title');
  titleElem.textContent = newValue;
}


const dropdownTitle = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown--title');
const dropdownOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .menu.categories a');
dropdownTitle.addEventListener('click', toggleMenuDisplay);
dropdownOptions.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', handleOptionSelected));

var categoriesMenu = document.querySelector('.categories.menu');
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var categoriesMenuShow = categoriesMenu.classList.contains("show");
  var isClickInsideElement = categoriesMenu.contains(event.target);
  if (isClickInsideElement == categoriesMenuShow ) {
    // categoriesMenu.classList.remove("show")
  }
});





//newly added code to determine outside clicks
var ignoreClickOnMeElement = document.getElementById('dropdown');

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var isClickInsideElement = ignoreClickOnMeElement.contains(event.target);
  if (!isClickInsideElement) {
      categoriesMenu.classList.remove("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown::before {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  top: 15px;
  right: 0;
  color: var(--cbl);
}

.dropdown .dropdown--title {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown .menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  top: 45px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: var(--cwh);
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px #ccc;
}

.dropdown .menu.show {
  max-height: 20em !important;
}

.dropdown .menu.show a {
  color: var(--cbl);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
}

.dropdown .menu a {
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  color: var(--cbl);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.dropdown .menu a:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--cblo40);
}

.dropdown .menu a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown--title">Choose category</div>
  <div class="categories menu">
    <a href="#" data-category="[15,16,26,27]" class="clicked">All</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/other/" data-category="15">Other</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/electronics/" data-category="16">Electronics</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/sports/" data-category="26">Sports</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/discount/product-category/toys/" data-category="27">Toys &amp; Games</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I think I can't get what you mean exactly. "I want to close the menu whenever a user clicks outside the menu." By this sentence I thought that you want to do something like this :( Could you please explain it more?

Comment: Sorry, wrong. Thank you for your efforts